# NetBeans can't generate Java Doc?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, illegalargumentexception

I don't know why, but it's been a problem for quite some time now.

I can't seem to generate Java Doc for most of my applications using NetBeans 7.2 (had the same problem with 7.1). I simply can't figure out why I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error decoding percent encoded characters
```

I know what the error means (English duh), but I can't find out why it says this. As far as I could see in my Documentation there shouldn't be any "percent encoded characters" unless I am missing what that means entirely.

Here is the entire code (one file only, and it's an interface so it's rather short):

```
package access;

import exception.DataException;
import java.util.List;
import table.Row;

/**
 *
 * @author Vipar
 */
public interface DataAccessor {
    /**
     * Reads data from a table.
     * 
     * @param table The table.
     * 
     * @param columns The columns to read, or null to read 
     * all the columns in the table.
     * 
     * @param selectionRow A set of filter columns and values 
     * use to subset the rows, or null to 
     * read all the rows in the table.
     * 
     * @param sortColumns The columns to sort, or null to read 
     * without sorting.
     * 
     * @return The list of rows.
     */
    List read(String table,
            String[] columns,
            Row selectionRow,
            String[] sortColumns) throws DataException;

    /**
     * Inserts data into a table.
     * 
     * @param table The table.
     * @param rows The rows to insert
     */
    void insert(String table, List rows) throws DataException;

    /**
     * Updates data in a table.
     * 
     * @param table The table.
     * 
     * @param selectionRow A set of filter columns and values 
     * used to subset the rows, or null to 
     * update all of the rows in the table.
     * 
     * @param updateRow A set of update columns and values.
     */
    void update(String table,
            Row selectionRow,
            Row updateRow) throws DataException;

    /**
     * Deletes data from a table.
     * 
     * @param table The table.
     * 
     * @param selectionRow A set of filter columns and values 
     * used to subset the rows, or null to 
     * delete all of the rows in the table.
     */
    void delete(String table,
            Row selectionRow) throws DataException;
}
```

Row and DataException does not have any documentation because currently both are empty. I just wanted to test how the documentation would look.

I use Java 1.7

Comment: Did you consult the NetBeans issue tracker? http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html Did you search the netbeans forum? http://forums.netbeans.org/

Comment: I've tried both yes, but I can't seem to really find this exact problem, but only variations. The solutions to those, doesn't solve the problem with this one.

Comment: Can you describe what exact steps you take to try and make NB create the docs?

Comment: I simply right-click on the project and press "Generate Javadoc". I don't go through any specific steps.

Comment: Look for the `%` character in `/** ... */` comments. Regex search `^\\s*/?\\*.*%`

Comment: The comment blocks are ok (i generated the code from link above with NB7.2, no errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your class --> javadoc is generated as usual.

Please check these settings (**`contextmenu of project -> Properties`**):

- **`Sources -> Encoding: UTF-8`**: What do you have here?
- **`Build -> Documenting`**: Do you have set some *Javadoc Options*? If you have settings in this textfield remove them and try again. Btw. what are your settings at *Documenting*?
- Since there's no [issue](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html) for this Exception, feel free to open one.

Comment: Just tried on my stationary computer...generated fine. I'll have to check out my laptop when I get the chance and get back to you. This is odd.

Comment: I've looked over all of the things you said, and the settings are no different than what you list. Yet it works on my stationary computer but not on this laptop :/

Comment: Strange, did you test generating javadoc for an existing Project (or only one class with some javadoc comment)? Next you can try reinstallation of JDK (or update to a newer version if possible).